# Should node js express server clustered processes listen on multiple sockets or one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, nginx, multiprocessing

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy in front of a node js express server. It is possible to use the node cluster module to create multiple server processes that listen on a single unix domain socket like so,

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http')

function start() {
  const expressServer = require('./main')
  const server = http.createServer(expressServer)
  server.listen(`/tmp/nginx.socket`)
}


if(cluster.isMaster) {
  // Master process: fork our child processes.
  const numWorkers = process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i += 1) {
    console.log('** Booting new worker **');
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // Respawn any child processes that die
  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('process %s died (%s). restarting...', worker.id, signal || code);
    cluster.fork();
  });

} else {

  start()

}
```

Alternatively I can spawn each process and have it listen on its own domain socket like so,

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http')

function start() {
  const expressServer = require('./main')
  const server = http.createServer(expressServer)
  server.listen(`/tmp/nginx-${process.env['WORKER_ID']}.socket`)
}


if(cluster.isMaster) {
  // Master process: fork our child processes.
  const numWorkers = process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i += 1) {
    console.log('** Booting new worker **');
    cluster.fork({'WORKER_ID': (i + 1)});
  }

  // Respawn any child processes that die
  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('process %s died (%s). restarting...', worker.id, signal || code);
    cluster.fork();
  });

} else {
  start()
}
```

Is there a compelling reason here to use multiple domain sockets?